# Conflicts casting between two objects from same class

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a base class in `TJSONPost` inside namespace `App.JSon`, in some places I have list of `TJSONPost` `Dim Posts As New List<\TJSONPost>` (Slash added to show between less than symbol) when I try to add new post I got strange error like this:

```
BC30311: Value of type 'Web1.App.JSON.TJSONPost' cannot be converted to 
'App.JSON.TJSONPost'.
```

I noticed a project name before the first definition!

Comment: The error shows that you have two different namespaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two classes with the same name (but different namespaces). Sounds like you need to change

```
Dim Posts As New List<TJSONPost>
```

to

```
Dim Posts As New List<Web1.App.JSON.TJSONPost>
```

Comment: your solution works great, but when i moved classes(base Class and others) in the same namespace this saved a lot.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Understanding you have two classes, one a child and one a parent.

If the list is of the base class, you can add items of the child class to it.  However, if the list is of the child class, you cannot add base class items to it.  I recommend you look to determine what type each object is, and possibly use the fully qualified name in the code to remove any doubts on the type.